# Filter and select random rows

Tags: excel, pandas, random, filter, openpyxl

I am not familiar with pandas and openpyxl package in Python but was just wondering if it is possible to select random, filtered rows from an excel file and save the output in a separate excel file ?

For example:
The data below represents what is in my excel file and what I would like to do is that:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F   G
1  x  -8  x  x  x  10/12/2019
3  x  +9  x  x  x  28/12/2019
4  x  +2  x  x  x  12/12/2019
1  x  -2  x  x  x  15/12/2019
4  x  -9  x  x  x  19/12/2019
5  x  -1  x  x  x  25/12/2019
```

1. Filter to only negative values in column C ("-ve")
2. Filter to only items (Column G) dated from 15/12/2019 onwards
3. Randomly select samples (for example, 2) from this filtered list
4. Save the 2 randomly selected samples in a new excel file, with the headers (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

Is there any way i could do this ?
Potentially, I will be using the script for well over 20 times.

Thank you !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from numpy.random import choice

df['G']=pd.to_datetime(df['G'])
#ensure that datelike column is of type datetime
out=df.loc[df['C'].le(-1) & df['G'].ge(pd.to_datetime('15/12/2019'))]
#Check your 1st and 2nd condition
out.loc[choice(out.index,2)].to_excel('filename.xlsx',index=False)
#get random 2 values from the filtered rows and save it to excel
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag. Would like to enquire another thing. Assuming that I manage generate a list with all negative values from the system (hence i will not need to filter only negative values now) but I would need to filter a new column <H> with the words " Standard Invoice", does the out=df.loc[df['C'].le("Standard Invoice")] work ?

Comment: @ejbeh no it will not work for that you need `df.loc[df['C'].str.contains("Standard Invoice")] ` also if the answer helped you pls try accepting the answer(cick on the tick to make it green)....thanks **:)**

Comment: Hi Anurag, I was playing around with the code and wonder if i were to change the criteria to before 15/12/2019 (assuming my data begins from 1/12/2019) , how should i alter the code to "before 15/12/2019" ? Many thanks !

Comment: @ejbeh chenge ge to lt for that case

Comment: @ejbeh so it becomes `out=df.loc[df['C'].le(-1) & df['G'].lt(pd.to_datetime('15/12/2019'))]` also if the answer helped you pls try accepting the answer(cick on the tick to make it green)....thanks :)